# How to find last matching line with ex?

Tags: ex

The `ex` command `$` navigates to the **first** character of the last line. Therefore, when doing a backwards search it skips the line it's currently on. How do I navigate to the last character with `ex`, or alternatively search for the last occurrence of a regular expression?

Example:

```
$ cd -- "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar foo bar > test.txt
$ ex -c '$' -c '?bar' -c 'visual' test.txt
```

At this point the cursor is on line 2 instead of line 4, as expected. Using `ex -c '?bar' -c 'visual' test.txt` produces the same result, even though I'd expect it to find the last line when wrapping around (`vim` does).

Using Vim 7.3.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `ex` starts at the *last* line - `ex -c '1' -c '?bar' -c 'visual' test.txt` moves the cursor to the last line.

Answer (score 2):

With my version of `ex`, `$+1?...` appears to start searching backward *after* the last line:

```
sh$ ex -version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Jul 12 2010 12:49:33)

sh$ ex -c '$+1?bar' -c visual test.txt
```

Comment: I first thought this would just wrap, but `ex -c '$+1' -c visual test.txt` shows that it's at the bottom of the file. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
ex -c '?bar' -c '/bar' -c 'visual' test.txt
```

By default, '?bar' will search for string `bar` from the last line of file but not search for string in last line. so when hit the first `bar` from last line, `/bar` make it correct, back to the `bar` in last line.

This will fail when the last line not contain string `bar`.

Comment: I get `E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command: G` and the cursor on line 2 when using your command. Which `ex` version are you using?

Comment: Just type enter, and the result will be right.

Comment: No, as I said the cursor is on line **2**.

Comment: Still the same result.

Comment: Fix bug. My mistake in `test.txt`. It contains a blank line at the end. So my first solution is failed, because it doesn't search for current line.

Comment: Now it works, but it also works if I remove the `-c 'G'`.

Comment: Final edited and explained.